# intent-filter for knowing when some app is being opened?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I would like to know which intent-filter use for listen when some app is being opened from my BroadcastReceiver.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Question is vague. Could you mention what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I want to start an activity when someone try to open whatsapp or another app like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android OS doesn't allow this behavior. No broadcast will be sent out when a particular app is opened.

However, you can have a service that is constantly running in the background and in that service you can use the ActivityManager to get a list of the current open apps. Based on that info, you can start your activity. This is a work around.

Answer (score 0):

There is no system broadcast sent out "when some app is being open", for privacy and security reasons.